# correct perl path for vim

Tags: perl, vim, perlbrew

I've installed perlbrew and it works: when I do a 'perl -v' in a terminal, it reports that I'm using perl 5.14. But gvim (vim instead works) still thinks that I'm using 5.10...

How do I set the perl path for gvim?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `PATH` variable in .vimrc:

```
let $PATH = "~/bin:" . $PATH
```

You can take a look at what it is by

```
:echo $PATH
```

Comment: thanks Axeman, it worked :-)
use v5.14;
system ('perl -v');
system ('which perl');

I'm using vim with the fantastic "Perl Support plugin", that implements a Perl-IDE for Vim/gVim

Answer (score 1):

There's also trick to enable path defined by perlbrew, so you don't need to change your `.vimrc` once you switched to other perl version:

```
" Enable perlbrew path
if has("gui_running") && filereadable($HOME . "/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc")
  let $PATH=system("source " . $HOME . "/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc; echo -n $PATH")
endif
```

Put this code in your `.vimrc` and restart vim

Comment: "Trick" is an interesting way to put this. My only concern is with all of the extra cruft that this would add to Vim.